# Есть ли готовые компоненты для Symfony (но можно и без привязки к нему), способные делать то, что делает Doctrine через рефлексию?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2, doctrine

Задача такова: есть некий набор данных, получаемых не из `БД`, на основании которого хочется уметь достаточно просто, например на основании `xml`-конфига (`yaml`, `php` - не особо важно), уметь создавать новые сущности неких классов уровня модели. Например, мы получили по `API` ответ от некоего сервиса, содержащий поля и их значения некоего объекта "Документ", и после на основании некоего конфига мы создаем новый инстанс класса `Document`, с заполненными свойствами нужными нам значениями. Свойства приватные. Понятно, что это делается на основании рефлексии, но хочется получить некую готовую разработку. Создавать через конструктор не вариант по своим причинам.

Есть что-то подобное, или придется все-таки писать самим?

Comment: а в чём сложность использовать doctrine? Симфони с ним очень дружит

Comment: @ArchDemon а как в нее заводить данные не через БД?

Comment: А чем не устраивает сериализация\десериализация. Получите те же модельки.

Comment: Извините, криво прочитал ваш вопрос. Возможно, вам нужно вот это jms/serializer https://packagist.org/packages/jms/serializer. Есть адаптер для симфони

Comment: @ArchDemon да, вы правы, сериализация и десериализация - это то, что мне нужно. Правда, я наверное скорее предпочту вариант с подобным функционалом из пакетов Symfony, в силу того, что мы с ним работаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача достаточно странная (вернее я хочу сказать что я не сталкивался с подобными задачами и для меня это странно). Вы хотите исходя из полученных данных формировать динамически модель. Ну даже если вы это сделаете, как вы динамически сформируете сервисы, которые обработают эту модель ?  Вы так же будете делать динамическое представление ? А даже если будете, то зачем вам модель ? Для взаимодействия с чем именно и рамках чего ?

Ежели вы все таки предполагаете какую модель вы получаете (а по-хорошему так и должно быть, раз вы пользуетесь api) то речь идет о serializer -  компонет существующий в Symfony. Вот [корень документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html).

У вас есть описанная модель в виде класса, где присутствуют все getters/setters и собственно методы.

Вы берете подходящий [Encoder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#encoders) (или цепочку encoders), каждый из которых умеет из ваших данных соответствующего формата делать массив, определяете нужный или нужные [Normalizers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers) что собственно работает непосредственно с моделью или свойствами модели, ежели они представляют собой объекты. В свою очередь туда нужно будет [добавить](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety) то что называют Exctractor (Если у вас в модели существуют объекты, а не просто свойства).

Ну и еще там есть ньюансы, от толстых до тонких, но весьма реализующих вашу задачу.

Однако если все-таки речь идет о динамическом создании модели, всё это выкидываем в урну :)

Comment: Да, я уже сам находил это решение, и вы правы, у меня заранее известно, что за модель будет использоваться. К слову, сеттеры и геттеры не обязательно должны быть, есть еще вариант с использованием PropertyNormalizer, например, когда используется рефлексия и и можно соответственно работать со свойствами класса напрямую.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko обязательны. Рефлексия используется в сериализаторе о котором я пишу для определения типов классов свойств (если свойства объекта у вас собственно объекты). Для гидрации же используется propertyaccessor , который в случае если свойства не публичные использует именно set/get . Включите дебаг во время нормализации или денормализации, увлекательно :)

Comment: хм, то есть если у меня у сущностей нет открытых сеттеров / геттеров и наружу торчат только бизнес-методы вроде "подписать документ", "аннулировать документ" и так далее, то использовать все это дело не выйдет?

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko а у вас в модели не должно быть бизнес логики. Всю логику должны выполнять сервисы. Модель же в данном случае выступает как хранение данных.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду доменные службы? Мы работаем по DDD, и в рамках этого подхода бизнес-логика как раз располагается либо в доменных службах, либо в бизнес-методах сущностей. А то, что предлагаете вы, называется анимичной моделью и считается антипаттерном.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko возможно :) вот тут по этому поводу интересно. https://m.habr.com/ru/post/346016/

Comment: Именно. Мы стараемся использовать БМПО.

Comment: Да, забыл вот что упомянуть - в статье по ссылке речь идет о том, что у них было монолитное приложение, с БМПО. У нас же изначально микросервисы, и в их рамках АМПО является антипаттерном. В итоге товарищ по ссылке и его компания используют АМПО как переходный паттерн, позволяющий разделить приложение на части, разобрав бизнес-логику и потом разнеся ее по микросервисам, но после того, как они сделают это, они либо останутся с носом, если не введут БМПО обратно, либо все же получат все преимущества DDD.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko очень дискуссионный вопрос. А можно ваш контакт ?  Телеграмм может ? У меня куча вопросов, интересно обсудить :)

Comment: Ох, лучше не надо ) На самой работе не могу, при этом предпочитаю оставлять саму работу целиком в офисе.